# Using dig axfr to perform a zone transfer from a Windows Server 2012 DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, dig

I'm working on setting up host auto-discovery for Nagios using DNS records.

When I try to use dig axfr to do a zone transfer (dig axfr local.domain.com), however, I get the following output:

```
[jwestbury@nagiosv local]# dig AXFR local.domain.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> AXFR local.domain.com
;; global options: +cmd
; Transfer failed.
```

The DNS server I'm querying is not showing anything in its logs for this query. If I change the domain to a non-existent one, I *do* see an entry in the DNS Server logs in Event Viewer, so I know the queries are hitting the DNS server fine.

Is there something special I need to do in order to allow AXFR transfers from the Nagios machine? Or is there somewhere else I should be looking for logs on the Nagios machine to indicate what might have happened when I tried to perform the transfer?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable and allow Zone Transfers for the zone you want to transfer. You can configure this on the Zone Transfers tab of the zone's properties pages.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I couldn't find where to allow the zone transfers -- thanks for pointing me to it!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Just an extra note for anyone who finds this in the future: For some reason, the context menu for the zone will have properties greyed out and unselectable sometimes. I solved this by just toggling my selection back and forth on the left-hand menu, then right-clicking the zone again. Not sure why it works like that, but, eh, it does.